# How to use ArcSDE to extract raster value (equivalent to PostGIS ST_Value function)

Tags: raster, enterprise-geodatabase, database

Is it possible to use ArcSDE SQL functions to extract a raster value from a vector point in a database (Oracle/PostgreSQL/SQL Server) with ArcSDE, and if so then how?

I want to use SQL to do this, since I need to continously update a column in a point feature class, and thought this was best done using a database trigger on creation of a new point in the feature class.

I know ArcSDE SQL functions  [ESRI ST_Geometry documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm) can handle vector data. But how do I interact with a raster dataset using ArcSDE funtions?

For a PostGIS database I would use ST_Value function for raster extract values, but what function should I use for ArcSDE?